# Why is bash rsync script not writing anything to file?

Tags: ubuntu, bash, rsync, cron

Ubuntu 9.10

**crontab -l**

0 1 * * * /root/cron/rsync-93.193.99.111 &> /root/cron/rsync-93.193.99.111.log
0 3 * * * tail -100 /root/cron/rsync-93.193.99.111.log | msmtp me@myemail.com

**ls -l /root/cron/rsync-93.193.99.111.log**

-rw-r--r-- root root /root/cron/rsync-93.193.99.111.log

The rsync-93.193.99.111.log file displays zero size in Nautilus.
I get an email, but it's empty.
Running tail -100, also shows emtpty output, so the email is correct.

**Why is the bash rsync script not writing anything to the file ?**

Comment: Whose crontab is it - `root`'s or your own?

Comment: login as my user, then sudo su, then crontab -e

Comment: I'm assuming it's root's crontab

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe it's because `&>` is not supported in `sh` which is the shell that `cron` uses. Use the explicit form:

```
0 1 * * * /root/cron/rsync-93.193.99.111 > /root/cron/rsync-93.193.99.111.log 2>&1
```

Also, you can do `sudo crontab -e` instead of doing `sudo su` then `crontab -e`.

Answer (score 1):

I concur with [Dennis's assessment of your problem](https://superuser.com/questions/193792/why-is-bash-rsync-script-not-writing-anything-to-file/193809#193809). But I have a couple of other points to mention.

Most importantly, don't do this:

```
0 1 * * * some command
0 3 * * * some other command that should run after the first one
```

What if the first command takes more or less than two hours? To make sure that the second command runs when the first finished, put them on a single line:

```
0 1 * * * /root/cron/rsync-93.193.99.111 >/root/cron/rsync-93.193.99.111.log 2>&1; tail -100 /root/cron/rsync-93.193.99.111.log | msmtp me@myemail.com
```

Also, you might want to take advantage of cron's automatic mailing of errors. (This assumes your system is set up properly for mail, which may not be the case if you have to run `msmtp` rather than `mail`.)

```
MAIL=me@myemail.com
0 1 * * * /root/cron/rsync-93.193.99.111 2>&1 | tee /root/cron/rsync-93.193.99.111.log | tail -n 100
```

Comment: You might want `&&` instead of `;` to make the `tail` dependent on the *success* of the `rsync` rather than just the *completion*.

Comment: @Dennis: For once, I felt `;` was more appropriate (and if I'd allowed myself to change the spec I'd have used `||`). After all the most likely use for the log is to see errors.